# Altering names for DNS servers where Primary and Parent records may not be changed at the same time

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a few Name Servers (BIND9) that I want to alter the Fully Qualified Name for.  As a hypothetical example:

- dns1.olddomain.com
- dns2.olddomain.com
- dns3.olddomain.com

Are the old Name Servers and I would like to use the following instead.

- dns1.newdomain.com
- dns2.newdomain.com
- dns3.newdomain.com

Presently all of the above records point to the same DNS servers, but the IP's of the new are different then the old (they route into the same machines).

My question here is if I update all the zones on my servers to use the new names for the SOA and NS, will I run into any issues if people using these servers do not update the registration records right away?  Or will they have an issue is they jump the gun and update the registration prior to my change?

I have done several tests resolving records using both scenarios, and so far I don't see that there is an issue with resolution.  However I am unsure if there is something I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood your question,

```
1. You are using same dns server

2. You already have name-servers dns1.olddomain.com dns2.olddomain.com dns3.olddomain.com configured on your dns server.

3. You want to add new name-servers dns1.newdomain.com dns2.newdomain.com dns3.newdomain.com on the same DNS server where your old name-servers are configured.

4. IP address for new name-servers are different than used for previous ones.

5. You want to update all your running zone records to new SOA and NS records.
```

If all the above things are true, then you will definately run into issues if people using old name-servers records do not update the registration records. There sites or applications will be down.

**If you change the registration records to new name-servers records after updating them to your zone then DNS Propagation will take upto 2-24 hours of time to propagate world-wide. (There will be downtime)**

**If you change the registration records to new name-servers records before updating them to your zone then also till the Zone is not updated they will not be resolved to any host. DNS Propagation will take upto 2-24 hours of time to propagate world-wide. As you update the zone they will resolve accordingly (There will be downtime)**

### You can add old as well new name-servers records for all your zone records, after the new name-servers also gets propagated world-wide you can remove the old name-servers. This is how you can avoid the downtime and update your name-servers.

Comment: Thanks,for this change I am not wiping out the records for dns[1-3].olddomain.com at all, they are still pointing to the old servers.

Comment: okay you mean you are not modifying all your previous zones enteries.

Comment: If it is like this then there will be no issues to the users using old name-servers records.

Comment: Correct, all the dns records listed (dns[1-3].olddomain.com and dns[1-3].newdomain.com still would point to the same servers.  What I am modifying is the NS and SOA returned but those servers to reflect the new names.

Comment: If you want to reflect the new records then you must have to change the records or add the new records with the old ones, only then they will reflect.

Comment: after new ones are propagated well you can remove the old ones.

Comment: THanks, can you edit your reply? It seems that even if my clients don't change to the new NS right away they wont see issues, as long as both the old and new names resolve and serve the same records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39035/discussion-between-imvikasmunjal-and-sky).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following correctly, these are the assumptions:

- Both new and old IP addresses will be available during the cutover.
- You are wanting to change the NS records in your zone file prior to making the change within your registrar account.
- A query made to the old IPs will always return the same answer that the new IPs will return. (because the IP addresses are shared) This holds true for before you change the NS records, and after you change the NS records.
- The registrar account will be updated to reflect the new nameservers after you have made this change.

This should be fine. You will get some warnings from online validation tools that you have both a NS record mismatch and a glue record mismatch, but this will not present a problem as the answers received from all IP addresses are consistent.

You will want to go ahead and execute your change on the registrar account once you have updated the NS records. The glue/NS mismatch warnings will go away once all devices on the internet have been given enough time to pick up the new NS records. You can see how long this interval will be by looking at the NS records defined on the TLD nameservers. Example.com is illustrated below as a reference, and the TTL is 172800 seconds. (48 hours)

```
$ dig +trace example.com
<snip>

example.com.            172800  IN      NS      a.iana-servers.net.
example.com.            172800  IN      NS      b.iana-servers.net.
;; Received 165 bytes from 192.41.162.30#53(l.gtld-servers.net) in 16 ms

<snip>
```